# Query com resultado duplicados

Tags: sql-server

Olá, estou batendo a cabeça aqui, não sei onde estou errando, ainda estou aprendendo então qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Tabela MUser

```sql
   | MUser_USER_NUMBER | MUser_USER_NAME |
   ---------------------------------------
   |        1          |     User1       |
```

Tabela MPassport

```sql
   | MPassport_USER_NUMBER| MPassport_NUMBER  | MPassport_EXPIRE_DATE |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1             |     12345678      |     2021-01-28        |
```

Tabela MCar

```sql
   | MCar_USER_NUMBER  | MCar_PLATE  | MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1          |  Plate 1    |      2020-12-07         |         2020-12-08         |         2021-07-01         | 
   |        1          |  Plate 2    |      2021-03-01         |         2021-03-02         |         2021-01-01         |
```

Tabela MDrive

```sql
   | MDrive_USER_NUMBER| MDrive_NUMBER  | MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1          |    12345678    |    2022-10-28      |
```

Query usada

```sql
SELECT MUser.MUser_USER_NUMBER As MUser_USER_NUMBER      
      ,MUser.MUser_USER_NAME AS MUser_USER_NAME       
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(Mpassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)      
          FROM MPassPort          
         WHERE MPassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MPassport.Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MPassport.Mpassport_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE                
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)           
          FROM MDrive          
         WHERE MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MDrive.MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MDrive.MDrive_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE  
      ,MCar.MCar_PLATE AS MCar_PLATE      
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)          
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar.MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE       
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)           
          FROM MCar         
         WHERE MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar.MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE       
      ,(SELECT ISNULL(MIN(MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE), NULL)            
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar.MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER ) As MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE   
  FROM (((MUser    
  LEFT JOIN MPassport On MUser.MUser_USER_NUMBER = MPassport.Mpassport_USER_NUMBER)                         
  LEFT JOIN MDrive On  MUser_USER_NUMBER = MDrive.MDrive_USER_NUMBER)               
  LEFT JOIN MCar On  MUser_USER_NUMBER = MCar.MCar_USER_NUMBER)  
 WHERE (SELECT Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MPassPort          
         WHERE Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND Mpassport_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'
    OR (SELECT MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MDrive          
         WHERE MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MDrive_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'     
    OR (SELECT MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'     
    OR (SELECT MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'     
    OR (SELECT MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE           
          FROM MCar          
         WHERE MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE < '2021/02/16'            
           AND MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE > '1900/01/01'            
           AND MCar_USER_NUMBER = MUser_USER_NUMBER) < '2021/02/16'
```

Resultado esperado

```sql
   | MCar_USER_NUMBER  | MUser_USER_NAME  | MPassport_EXPIRE_DATE | MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_PLATE  | MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1          |      User1       |       2021-01-28      |                    |  Plate 1    |      2020-12-07         |         2020-12-08         |                            | 
   |        1          |      User1       |       2021-01-28      |                    |  Plate 2    |                         |                            |         2021-01-01         |
```

Resultado recebido

```sql
   | MCar_USER_NUMBER  | MUser_USER_NAME  | MPassport_EXPIRE_DATE | MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_PLATE  | MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE | MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |        1          |      User1       |       2021-01-28      |                    |  Plate 1    |      2020-12-07         |         2020-12-08         |         2021-01-01         | 
   |        1          |      User1       |       2021-01-28      |                    |  Plate 2    |      2020-12-07         |         2020-12-08         |         2021-01-01         |
```

Alguma alma caridosa pode ajudar um novato que está perdido?

Essa query na verdade ainda tem mais coisa, mas se conseguir funcionar isso o resto seria somente adicionar as outras tabelas.

De início muito obrigado pela paciencia de ler tudo isso.

---

### Editado

DB

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [Teste]
GO

USE Teste
GO

CREATE TABLE MUser (
    MUser_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MUser_USER_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    MUser_USER_NAME nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MUser_USER_NUMBER PRIMARY KEY (MUser_USER_NUMBER),
);

    INSERT MUser (
               MUser_USER_NUMBER
              ,MUser_USER_NAME
          ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'User1'
           )
           
CREATE TABLE MCar (
    MCar_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MCar_USER_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    MCar_PLATE nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE date NULL,
    MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE  date NULL,
    MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MCar_PLATE PRIMARY KEY (MCar_PLATE),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MCar_USER_NUMBER FOREIGN KEY (MCar_USER_NUMBER) REFERENCES MUser(MUser_USER_NUMBER)
);

    INSERT MCar (
               MCar_USER_NUMBER
              ,MCar_PLATE
              ,MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE
              ,MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE
              ,MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE
           ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'Plate1'
              ,N'2020-12-07'
              ,N'2020-12-08'
              ,N'2021-07-01'
           )
           
    INSERT MCar (
               MCar_USER_NUMBER
              ,MCar_PLATE
              ,MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE
              ,MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE
              ,MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE
           ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'Plate2'
              ,N'2021-03-01'
              ,N'2021-03-02'
              ,N'2021-01-01'
           )
           
CREATE TABLE Mpassport (
    Mpassport_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Mpassport_USER_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Mpassport_NUMBER nvarchar(50) NULL,
    Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Mpassport_USER_NUMBER PRIMARY KEY (Mpassport_USER_NUMBER),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Mpassport_USER_NUMBER FOREIGN KEY (Mpassport_USER_NUMBER) REFERENCES MUser(MUser_USER_NUMBER)
);

    INSERT Mpassport (
               Mpassport_USER_NUMBER
              ,Mpassport_NUMBER
              ,Mpassport_EXPIRE_DATE
           ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'12345678'
              ,N'2021-01-28'
           )
           
CREATE TABLE MDrive (
    MDrive_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    MDrive_USER_NUMBER nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
    MDrive_NUMBER nvarchar(50) NULL,
    MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE date NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MDrive_USER_NUMBER PRIMARY KEY (MDrive_USER_NUMBER),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MDrive_USER_NUMBER FOREIGN KEY (MDrive_USER_NUMBER) REFERENCES MUser(MUser_USER_NUMBER)
);

    INSERT MDrive (
               MDrive_USER_NUMBER
              ,MDrive_NUMBER
              ,MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE
           ) 
    VALUES (
               N'1'
              ,N'12345678'
              ,N'2022-10-28'
           )
```

---

### Editado

O sistema será o seguinte:
※ apenas uma parte do sistema

Um usuário cadastra os dados de expiração dos documentos

MDrive_EXPIRE_DATE = Carteira de motorista
MCar_SHAKEN_EXPIRE_DATE = Documento do carro
MCar_JIBAISEKI_EXPIRE_DATE = Seguro obrigatório do carro
MCar_INSURANCE_EXPIRE_DATE = Seguro contra terceiros do carro

Fora isso tem outros documentos, apenas coloquei esse para não ficar longo.

Na parte da carteira de motorista seria apenas uma, mas na parte do carro, o usuário poderia ter mais de um.

O que eu estou tentando fazer seria para que ao logar no sistema ativasse esse código que olharia os documentos que irão vencer entre hoje e uma data determinada para o documento, no exemplo aí eu coloquei mais ou menos 3 meses para frente.

Na parte do carro, pode acontecer de um dos dados não serem imputados, pois seria controle do escritório, e o funcionário ainda não entregou os documentos, por isso coloquei a clausula >1900-01-01, pois o default da data no DB seria essa.
Para que o sistema ignorasse esses carros que estão sem os dados corretos.

A data <2021/02/16 (3 meses a partir da data de login no sistema) seria o máximo que procuraria, para avisar o funcionário que o documento venceria em tal data, para ter tempo da pessoa renovar.

Comment: Importante [edit] a pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). Importante notar que cada comunidade tem seus critérios específicos (mesmo se o tema for similar), por isso é importante conhecer a documentação de cada uma.

Comment: Como a conversa ficou longa, foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116503/discussion-on-question-by-kristian-francischini-query-com-resultado-duplicados). Quem quiser participar, orientar ou acrescentar algo, basta clicar no link fornecido.